# Creating a range slider for dates

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a range slider using HTML and CSS.

I want the range to be between two dates.

I looked up the code for a range slider and found this,

```
<form method="post" action="/action_page_post.php">
  <div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="price-min">Price:</label>
    <input type="range" name="price-min" id="price-min" value="200" min="0" max="1000">
    <label for="price-max">Price:</label>
    <input type="range" name="price-max" id="price-max" value="800" min="0" max="1000">
  </div>
    <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    <p>The range slider can be useful for allowing users to select a specific price range when browsing products.</p>
  </form>
```

This is perfect in terms of what I want, but I want the minimum and maximum values to be dates. Lets say I want the slider to range from 2018-05-29 and 2018-06-25.

I'm not sure how to make this happen...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this sample in CodePen provided by Rod Reyes. It's using jquery-ui plugin.

```js
 $(function () {
            $("#slider-range").slider({
                range: true,
                min: new Date('2010.01.01').getTime() / 1000,
                max: new Date('2014.01.01').getTime() / 1000,
                step: 86400,
                values: [new Date('2013.01.01').getTime() / 1000, new Date('2013.02.01').getTime() / 1000],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#amount").val((new Date(ui.values[0] * 1000).toDateString()) + " - " + (new Date(ui.values[1] * 1000)).toDateString());
                }
            });
            $("#amount").val((new Date($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) * 1000).toDateString()) +
                " - " + (new Date($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) * 1000)).toDateString());
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
    <label for="amount">Date range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" size="100" />
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

See it in action also here: https://codepen.io/2rod/pen/JtIki

Answer (score 0):

You should try [this](https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider) plugin. I think this does exactly what you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iThing.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jQDateRangeSlider-min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<!--
      $("#slider").dateRangeSlider();
    //-->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the basic usage of the plugin. Unfortunately it's a 3rd party plugin if the link went not accessible you may lose the plugin as well.

Comment: what he wants is a date range slider. we don't have to invent the wheel. if someone has already done the job. everything is in the documentation. if there's no documentation or guide to use the tool yeah sure I'm happy to give the code sample. at least I'm trying to help him rather pointing procedures. That was the StackOverflow when I join this community.

Comment: I have updated my answer with provided code snippet and you better understand this is a 3 party tool from 3 party library. when the link went unavailable no point to add code snippet as well.

Comment: It's been established for quite a while that a link to a library on its own doesn't constitute a good answer, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289075/7508700) for example. When you have information about a potentially helpful library that doesn't really need any further explanation, you could probably avoid the back-and-forth by posting it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks should I remove my answer?